# Generator object has no Boxes

Tags: python, object-detection, yolov8

I am trying to run an object detection code in raspberry pi 4

```
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO
import argparse
import supervision as sv

def parse_argument() -> argparse.Namespace:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="YOLOv8 Live")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--webcam-resolution",
        default=[1280, 720],
        nargs=2,type=int
        )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def main():
    args = parse_argument()
    frame_width, frame_height = args.webcam_resolution

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, frame_width)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, frame_height)
    model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
    
    box_annotator = sv.BoxAnnotator(
        thickness=2,
        text_thickness=2,
        text_scale=1
        )

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        results = model(frame, show=True, stream=True)
        
        detections = sv.Detections.from_ultralytics(results)
        labels = [
            f"{model.model.names[class_id]} {confidence:0.2f}"
            for _, confidence, class_id, _
            in detections
        ]        
        frame = box_annotator.annotate(
            scene=frame,
            detections=detections,
            labels=labels
        )
        
        cv2.imshow("Object Detection and Tracking", frame)
        
        if(cv2.waitKey(30) == 27):
            break

main()
```

I keep getting the error: Attribute error 'generator' object has no 'boxes'. Please someone help me, i have no idea why. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing the packages but nothing seams to work. Here is the full error with traceback

this is the full error with traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/obioheme/Projects/Pan-Tilt-Camera/opencv-yolov8.py", line 52, in 
> main()
> File "/home/obioheme/Projects/Pan-Tilt-Camera/opencv-yolov8.py", line 35, in main
> detections = sv.Detections.from_ultralytics(results)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/supervision/detection/core.py", line 262, in from_ultralytics
> xyxy=ultralytics_results.boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy(),
> AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'boxes'

Comment: What's the full error with traceback?

Comment: @Carcigenicate this is the full error with traceback


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/obioheme/Projects/Pan-Tilt-Camera/opencv-yolov8.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/obioheme/Projects/Pan-Tilt-Camera/opencv-yolov8.py", line 35, in main
    detections = sv.Detections.from_ultralytics(results)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/supervision/detection/core.py", line 262, in from_ultralytics
    xyxy=ultralytics_results.boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy(),
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'boxes'

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to use `stream=True` as long as you run inference on a single frame at a time. Stream mode returns generator, `stream=False` will return a list of result objects, it is more convenient in this case. Second, for one frame it will be a list with a single result object, so you can refer directly to the `results[0]`:

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    results = model(frame, show=True, stream=False)    
    detections = sv.Detections.from_ultralytics(results[0])
```

If the stream mode is preferable, you need to iterate over the results generator. More information is here: https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#key-features-of-predict-mode

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with a proverb of my country. When the car is broken getting out of it and get on it again wont fix anything :)
The problem is that result is empty. Maybe there wasn't any detection in the picture. Maybe the picture is not picture!!! When you are getting frames in mobile systems like raspberry there are many reasons that getting a frame wont work properly. Take following steps to find the problem.

1. Plot the image you are working on
2. Check len(result)>0
3. print result[0].boxes